# HTTP Session Replication in JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: jboss7.x, httpsession, infinispan, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to get my JSF Web Application deployed in a "domain" cluster with two nodes.

I am unable to get the HTTP Session replicated between the nodes.

I have configured my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>

  <distributable></distributable>

</web-app>
```

and **jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>thumbzup-admin</context-root>

    <!--replication-config>
      <replication-trigger>SET_AND_NON_PRIMITIVE_GET</replication-trigger>
      <replication-granularity>SESSION</replication-granularity>
    </replication-config-->
  <replication-config>
    <cache-name>custom-session-cache</cache-name>
    <replication-trigger>SET</replication-trigger>
    <replication-granularity>ATTRIBUTE</replication-granularity>
    <!--replication-field-batch-mode>true</replication-field-batch-mode-->
    <use-jk>false</use-jk>
    <max-unreplicated-interval>30</max-unreplicated-interval>
    <snapshot-mode>INSTANT</snapshot-mode>
    <snapshot-interval>1000</snapshot-interval>
    <replication-mode>SYNCHRONOUS</replication-mode>
    <!--session-notification-policy>com.example.CustomSessionNotificationPolicy</session-notification-policy-->
  </replication-config>
</jboss-web>
```

and Infinispan Cache Container in **domain.xml**;

```
<cache-container name="web" aliases="standard-session-cache" default-cache="repl" module="org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan">
                    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                    <replicated-cache name="repl" mode="ASYNC" batching="true">
                        <file-store/>
                    </replicated-cache>
                    <replicated-cache name="sso" mode="SYNC" batching="true"/>
                    <distributed-cache name="dist" l1-lifespan="0" mode="ASYNC" batching="true">
                        <file-store/>
                    </distributed-cache>
                </cache-container>
```

But I am unable to retrieve a session created on NODE1 when using the same SESSIONID on NODE2.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The name
    "custom-session-cache"
you defined in jboss-web.xml does not seem to match any cache inside domain.xml. Remove "**cache-name**" property completely to use the value of "default-cache" property of the "web" container or add a cache entry with that name